# glsurfaceview ignores admob height

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, admob, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView that covers the whole screen and added an admob ad. The problem is that a part of the surface view is now covered by the ad which is not good since the user will not be able to use some controls. What I want is when an ad is active the surface view to be initialized with less that the full height of screen, namely minus the admob ad height.

Whatever I tried be it RelativeLayout or linear layout in another linear layout what I get is that the ad moves my surface view out of the view while the surface view still has the screen height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use layout_weight for glsurfaceview, like `layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1".`
Android will automatically calculate the height for your glsurfaceview.

Comment: I did manage to reduce the height of the glsurfaceview but it still shows starting behind the ad. Should I hardcode the top of the surface view based on the height of the ad?

Comment: Try to use linerlayout with order, glsurfaceview, then your ad view. And set glsurfaceview to layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1", and set ad view to layout_height="20dp".